# Android - dynamically change the shape file attributes

Tags: android

I have a shape.xml file something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%"
            android:toDegrees="-45" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:color="@color/red" />

                <solid android:color="@color/red" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I have to change the attributes of this file dynamically. I know that i have to use GradientDrawable but i am not be able to get the exact configuration as defined in this file. Can anyone help.